# Table Name Availability check with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create a table with php script. and before that i am trying to check for available name with PHP. but it is not working.

even if i enter a table which exits it is showing **Not Exists: Incorrect table name**

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `$mainnamechk`;";

if (mysql_query($sql1))
{
echo "<img width='35' height='25' src='img/good.png' title='Database $mainnamechk Exists'>";
  }
else
  {
   echo "Not Exists:" . mysql_error();
  echo"<br>";

  }
```

Comment: use `show tables;` query first to get the list of tables.

Comment: @TimWithers yes i can use that. but i want a input box and when my people want to create DB.. they will check using this.. cause they don't know php and all.. so i am creating this... but it is not working..

Comment: $sql1 = create table if not exist `table`() return true;

    if ($sql1){
         echo "";
}

Comment: @BlackCoder: Your users don't have to know PHP.  The code would run a `SHOW TABLES` query and examine the output.  If the table is in the output, it exists.  If it isn't in the output, it doesn't exist.  (Out of curiosity, why do you want this application to be able to create tables anyway?  In *most* cases that's not the right design.)

Comment: It sounds like you're creating tables dynamically, which is a terrible and backwards approach to nearly any problem.

Comment: @David actually every day... hundreds of tables will be added in this project.. if i use show tables.. they there will be thousands of tablas :O

Comment: @BlackCoder: Which further indicates that this is probably not the right design.  Though it doesn't affect the solution to this specific question.  `SHOW TABLES` still, well, shows you the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the information_schema

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = '" . $database . "') AND (TABLE_NAME = '" . $tablename . "');
```

This will return a 1 if it exists, or a 0 if it does not.

```
$database = "databasename";
$table = "tablename";
$con = new mysqli(/* info */);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = '" . $database . "') AND (TABLE_NAME = '" . $table . "'");
// $result == 1 or 0
```

Comment: tried but not working :(

Comment: What does not work about it? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in xxx.php on line 15 AND line 15 is `$database = maintable; SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES` the code is used is `SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = '" . $database . "') AND (TABLE_NAME = '" . $mainnamechk . "');`

Comment: The name of your database is maintainable? Did you enclose that in quotes?

Keep in mind you should be setting it to a result, I will update my answer

Comment: yes the name is maintable and i used like this $database = "maintable";

Comment: Try the code as-is above, substituting the values for `$database` and `$table`. What happens?

Comment: ok.. see this screen shot - http://snap.ashampoo.com/5ZOq5LJ6

and error is `Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in xxx.php on line 17` and line 17 is nothing :(

Comment: Aha! Silly silly mistake on my part, pass the `$con` variable first. I've shown this in my answer. After that it should all work.

Comment: actially i am connecting to database using include_once("config.php"); then shoud i need to use `$con = new mysqli(/* info */);` this again ?

Comment: You will use whatever your mysqli connection variable is inside the config.php, provided it isn't closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'"))==1) 
    echo "Table exists";
else echo "Table does not exist";
```

Comment: it is showing `Table does not exist` for all :( even if i enter an existing table name

Comment: use %, like '%<table_name>%'

Comment: already tried in all possible ways :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql1=MYSQL_QUERY('SELECT count(name) FROM "'.$mainnamechk.'" LIMIT 1');

if(mysql_num_rows($sql1)==0)
{
 echo 'Not exists';
}
else
{
echo 'Exists';
}
```

Comment: i got an error " Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in xxxxxxxx.php on line 17" and the line 17 is `if(mysql_num_rows($sql1)==0)`

Comment: I have fixed already, edited the note.

Comment: It should work now. Try again

Comment: still error - Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given inxxx.php on line 17

Comment: use this one:  FROM " '.$mainnamechk.' " (just put " the front and the end)     If error will appear again, in that case the problem is about $mainnamechk.

Comment: iF will not work give an echo to your sql. And look how will PHP return you $mainnamechk.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'database name' 
    AND table_name = 'table_name'
LIMIT 1;
```